# How to get containing iframe id when the iframe document is clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am looking for a way to use jQuery to get the id of an iframe when its document element is clicked. The code will be run initialed from the parent window.

```
$frame = $("<iframe class='frame'></iframe>").load(function(){
    $(this).contents().bind("click", function(e){
       alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
}
```

the alert reads **undefined**.

Alternatively I also tried:

alert($(this), window.parent).attr("id");

Comment: is code to be run in parent page or in Iframe page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice that the previous example only works when you give your iframe a border and click on that (i.e. clicking on the iframe element, not on the document element it contains, which I believe was what you asked for).

The following code binds a mouseover handler to the iframe, which grabs the iframe's ID before binding an onclick handler to its contents. Note that this will only work if the iframe points at another page on your site, not one on another domain.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $('iframe').bind('mouseover', function(){

          var iframeID = $(this).attr('id');

          $(this).contents().unbind(); 

          $(this).contents().bind('click', function(){

              alert(iframeID);  
          });
       }); 

    });
```

Comment: I assumed it needed css already.  I still get undefined in the click event.  Here it is in jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/UFPTX/5/  this is my best attempt so far http://jsfiddle.net/UFPTX/6/

Comment: You were missing an ID on your iframe. Try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/UFPTX/8/

Comment: @Finglish Did the code work out for you? If so please vote up :]

Answer (score 0):

Without content to the iframe, according to Dio's example fiddle is as follows, http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/FUUz9/

```
<iframe id="frame" class='frame' width="200" height="200"></iframe>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an old question but I am still putting an answer for those who still got this problem :

HTML Content :

```
<iframe class='frame' id="iframe-1"></iframe>
```

JQuery to get iframe id while clicking on its content :

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.iframe').each(function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        _this.contents().find('body').focus(function(){
            var iframe_id = _this.attr('id');
            alert(iframe_id); // do whatever with it
        });
    });
},1000);
```

*I hope it helps...*

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('iframe').click(function(){
   Id=$(this).attr('id');
   alert(Id);
 });
});
```

Comment: This is still not working for me. I have elaborated on my question